# How can I make a card clickable and navigate to another page inside TabBarView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a card clickable and navigate to another page 'forecastWeather.dart'. But I can't seem to figure out how I can fix the error I'm getting. The error message says

> Another exception was thrown: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

I'm using a TabBarView with two tabs and one contains a card which should be clickable and navigate to another page 'forecastWeather.dart'. Please help!

Comment: I think you should do it like this "Navigator.of(context).push" can you try this

Answer (score 1):

In order to get use `navigator.push`, you must pass the context of your widget and have a `MaterialApp` somewhere in your tree, you do both, so the code should work, but it doesn't.

The reason is simple, the context you are passing is outdated, you are first creating the context when the build method begins, at that point, there is no material app, then you add a material app, but the context already exists, so the context you are passing when calling `Navigator.push(context ...` has no `MaterialApp`.

A possible fix is to use the `Builder` widget to make a new context after you create the `MaterialApp` widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // context has no material app.
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        // this context does have a material app and is safe to use.
        return DefaultTabController( ... );
      }
    ),
  );
}
```

Another fix is to move the code into a new widget with it's own context:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // this context was created after the material app.
    return DefaultTabController(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution and the explanation.. I followed your solution and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use `get: ^4.6.1` package.
with this package you just need to use this for any navigation:

```
Get.to(ForecastWeather());
```

this package have so other features read its document here
[1]: https://pub.dev/packages/get